# DRYing up conditional validation in a Ruby class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry

How can I dry up my validation code? I have a `Discussion` model that has a a `category` and `status` fields. The status value depends on the category value. A discussion where `category == 'question'` can only have a status in `STATUSES[:question]`, for example.

```
  STATUSES   = {
    question:   %w[answered],
    suggestion: %w[pending planned started completed declined],
    problem:    %w[started solved]
  }
  validates :status, allow_blank: true, inclusion: { in: STATUSES[:question] },   if: lambda { self.category == 'question' }
  validates :status, allow_blank: true, inclusion: { in: STATUSES[:suggestion] }, if: lambda { self.category == 'suggestion' }
  validates :status, allow_blank: true, inclusion: { in: STATUSES[:problem] },    if: lambda { self.category == 'problem' }
```

I'm using Rails 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:inclusion :in` accepts a lambda itself:

```
validates :status, inclusion: { in: lambda { |o| STATUSES[o.category.to_sym] } }
```

Documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_inclusion_of